# Why my Bing Search API News returns empty string?

Tags: api, rest, search, yql, bing

I'm subscribed to the free Bing Search API on the Windows Azure website.  What I want to do is add a panel to my website that uses purely client-side code (javascript) to query the Bing Search Api for News results, which I want to be sorted by relevance.

In order to get this to work I found this interesting article which talks about how to store your authentication information in YQL (Yahoo Query Language) and use it as a proxy to query the Bing Search API at: http://derek.io/blog/2010/how-to-secure-oauth-in-javascript/

So, here is what I did:

1) Develop a YQL Open Data Table which contains my Bing Key and a query parameter.  Here is the XML Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<table xmlns="http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/schema/table.xsd">
    <meta>
        <sampleQuery>
            select * from {table} where query="washington"
        </sampleQuery>
    </meta>
    <bindings>
       <!-- SearchResponse.News.RelatedSearches.NewsRelatedSearch -->
        <select produces="json">    

            <urls><url>https://a889dc2f-d0d4-4d16-9f4e-401c750deb04:IFU5P1aw5HAFJsMgOoxSyAAQyAh+m5asVkEq3GG9xIU@api.datamarket.azure.com/Bing/Search/v1/Composite?Sources=%27news%27</url></urls>

            <inputs>
                <key id="Query" default="'new york bonds'+NewsCategory='rt_Business'" paramType="query" />
            </inputs>

        </select>                        
    </bindings>
</table>
```

See where I put the `ConsumerID` and `AccountKey`?  It's at the very beginning of the URL (separated by a colon).

2) Save this data table in YQL's hosted storage.  I get back execute, select, and update Storage Addresses.  This allows me to hide my Auth information, while eliminating the need for a server-side proxy.

3) Use the Execute Storage Key given by: store://6sVu1WUPgFrgFcOv1bH81U to make a YQL query from, say, the YQL Console.  Let's use the following query:

```
use "store://6sVu1WUPgFrgFcOv1bH81U" as T;
select * from T where Query="'Texas bonds'&NewsCategory='rt_Business'";
```

Uh oh... we hit the first error.  The YQL Console eats it and spits out "Invalid JSON Document."  Okay, so I think the console doesn't know how to parse this query.

Fine, then let's just use the REST URL to perform the query.  The URL is:

```
https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=use%20%22store%3A%2F%2F6sVu1WUPgFrgFcOv1bH81U%22%20as%20T%3B%20select%20*%20from%20T%20where%20Query%3D%22%27Texas%20bonds%27%26NewsCategory%3D%27rt_Business%27%22%3B&format=json&diagnostics=true
```

Great!  But something interesting is happening here.  The diagnostics in the resulting JSON string say:

> "Failed to read from storage... not a valid storage address."

I could care less, as long as I get a good JSON string I don't care. But here is where the problem occurs.  Try using the resulting REST URL for *this* query:

```
use "store://6sVu1WUPgFrgFcOv1bH81U" as T;
select * from T where Query="'Texas bonds'&NewsCategory='rt_Business'&NewsSortBy='Relevance'";
```

**The result is an empty string (with the same storage url error).**

WHY?! This is the exact same query, but it just sorts the News Results by relevance instead of date.

Does anyone know what the heck is going on here?

Thanks in advance for your time, it is MUCH appreciated.

P.S. I've tried putting in other key id's to make the XML code better looking but it would always screw up the query. Please let me know if you can get this working I will love you forever.

Do you think it might have to be done using OAuth?